# Growl notifications in Fullscreen Apps

Tags: macos, mac, fullscreen, growl

I've just re-installed Growl and noticed it's version 2.0 and for some reason cannot get growl notifications whilst in fullscreen applications like Chrome, Safari or iTunes. 
The notification is displayed on the first desktop space though.
Has this always been the case and I only just noticed? 

Using growl 2.0 and ML 10.8.2
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spaces as well as FullScreen (which it sounds like you are) Yes, this has always been the case.  However, with OS X the default is Desktop #1.  You can set your growl Notifications for a different desktop and they won't appear when not on that desktop.

I hope this answers your question.